# Include problems with FreeRTOS Simple Demo on PIC32MX

Tags: c, include, mplab, freertos, pic32

I've been trying to get my hands on freeRTOS at work for a few days now.
Since I'm done reading the documentation on the website, I'm now trying to work a simple demo on a PIC32 starter kit (with MPLABX.

So far it works, the led blinks and the messages are sent and received (yeahy).
However, although it doesnt prevent me from running the demo, I get a huge load of red exclamation marks all over the includes and usages of specific types, it's a bit odd.
I've decided not to care too much for the moment.

But now that I'm trying to include a personal header file, I get a failing build.
I have absolutely no idea why this would happen since I've always included header files that same way and never had that kind of problem.

Any help would be really appreciated both on why I can't make that include work and why I got a zillion exclamation marks.

Thanks in advance and please tell me if you need additional informations.

code:

```
#include "Menu.h"
```

error:

> ../main_blinky.c:181:18: fatal error: Menu.h: No such file or directory

**EDIT:**

I'm done with the zillion exclamation marks pb, I've searched for the missing .h files in the freeRTOS directory and added the paths to the inculde directories option of the compiler.

It looks like you have to add several include folders but I don't remember having read any of that in the documentation probably because it doesn't prevent the demo from running I guess.

Now I need to deal with the other pb. I'll tell you what.

Comment: Hi, please post your edit2 as an answer and accept it as an aswer ;-) This way the question will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. following what I did in edit1, I thought "hey, what if the project's own directory isn't part of the include folders? naaaah can't be... ok let's be sure and give it a try"

And guess what...? it wasn't.

I had no clue this could ever happen but maybe that's just because I'm ignorant to some point.

Anyways, just added the project's path to the include folders path list and now both problems are solved, I hope this will help someone one day or another.